# Selenium Web Driver Ruby- Element not visible exception

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver

The web page snippet looks like this:

```
<div id="HPSearchInput">
<form>
<ul></ul>
<input type="submit" data-ember-action="3" class="ch-btn searchBtn"        value="Search">
</form>
```

I am using the following css selector to click on the search button:

```
wait = Selenium::WebDriver::Wait.new(:timeout => 10) # seconds
wait.until { (driver.find_element(:css => "#HPSearchInput > form > input.ch-  btn.searchBtn")).click() }
```

It is giving me the error: ElementNotVisibleError

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Show us the full error stack..

Comment: [remote server] file:///C:/Users/x_x/AppData/Local/Temp/webdriver-profile2013102
8-7084-xaov0q/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js
:8225:in `unknown': Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacte
d with (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::ElementNotVisibleError)
        from [remote server] file:///C:/Users/x_x/AppData/Local/Temp/webdriver-p
rofile20131028-7084-xaov0q/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command
_processor.js:10816:in `unknown'
        from [remote server] file:///C:/Users/x_x/AppData/Local/Temp/webdriver-p..........

Comment: Please add any extra information into your question and not in the comments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is it an element that doesn't appear right away?  If so, try:

```
wait.until { driver.find_element(:css => "#HPSearchInput > form > input.ch-  btn.searchBtn").displayed? }
driver.find_element(:css => "#HPSearchInput > form > input.ch-  btn.searchBtn").
```

Comment: Thank you it solves the problem. I have accepted it as the answer. Additionlaly can you please tell me why Elementnotvisible error is shown because clearly the "element" is visible on the page.

Comment: Selenium uses several criteria to determine that an element is "visible", mostly Javascript interactions with the DOM. There are some much more thorough answers out there than I can provide here. The important thing to understand is that the loading of most elements on the page is _asynchronous_, so you can't necessarily predict exactly when they'll be visible. To wit: JavaScript.